# Access data created in a route and use it in another [Sinatra]

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How can I access data I created in one of my routes and use them in another route? For example

**main.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'other.rb'

get '/foo' do
  @test = "Hi"
end
```

And use it in..

**other.rb**

```
get '/bar' do
  erb :test_view
end
```

..so in the following view I can say

**test_view.erb**

```
<%= @test %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself. I have written a helper method.

**main.rb**

```
helpers do
  def global_test
    @test = "Hi"
  end
end
```

**other.rb**

```
get '/bar' do
  global_test
  erb :test_view
end
```

**test_view.erb**

```
<%= @test %>
```

It renders "Hi" on `:test_view`.

Comment: not sure but didn't you miss a `end` for `def global_test`?

Comment: Your solution is going to fail hard when you have more than one user. Imagine that user1 goes to foo and you set a certain value for him in the helper, then user2 goes to foo setting a new value before user1 gets to bar? A proper solution involves sessions.